# Extract substring from text file

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a batch script that can extract a value between two xml tag in batch.

I get my xml file by executing a curl cmd that I redirect to a temporary file:

```
curl -X POST -H "key:value" -i http://mywebsite/ask -d "<xml body>" > tmp
```

Then, I search my tag like this:

```
findstr "<abc:id>" tmp
```

I can see in the cmd console that the correct line are displayed:

```
<abc:id>the_id_that_i_want</abc:id>
```

But after that I can't get my id.

I have already tried to forward the 'findstr' result to a file, then reading it without success.

I have also tried to use this script:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "<abc:id>" tmp') do set var=%%i
echo %var%
```

But my script crashes on echo statement.

So, how can extract my id and set it in a variable?

Comment: Just ... why? Why are you trying to parse XML with a batch file?

Comment: Several native scripting languages available to you in Windows that have methods to parse XML files without have to brute force it with a batch-file.  Jscript, Vbscript and Powershell.  Microsoft also created two utilities that can parse XML files.  Log Parser and MSXSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One things is to write the command : `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. If not, the 'for' cannot be run correctly.

One other things was olso to use variable not with `%` tags, but `!` tags. That let use variable text with redirectors (`>` and `<`).

At the end, I get that script :

```
curl -X POST -H "key:value" -i http://mywebsite/ask -d "<xml body>" > tmp

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "<abc:id>" tmp') do set var=%%i

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=<abc:id>" %%a in ("!var!") do set var2=%%b

DEL tmp

ECHO Id : !var2!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /F "tokens=2delims=<>"...
```

Takes the line

```
<abc:id>the_id_that_i_want</abc:id>
```

and tokenises it using `<` and `>` as delimiters.

The first token is `abc:id`, the second `the_id_that_i_want` and the third `/abc:id`

so you need to select the second.

The `echo` crashes because the string being `echo`ed contains redirectors (`>` and `<`)